# Git: How to avoid merging / fetching a wrong remote in a branch?

Tags: git

Say that I'm on my feature branch XXXX and issuing a `git pull bad_remote master` here is a *BAD* thing to do (in the way our workflow and branches are set up, of course).

Is there a way to tell git (or via some Bash magic) to NOT EVER merge or fetch from that remote if you're not in a local branch named YYYY (the branch that is supposed to receive the bad_remote changes)? Having it spitting to me some bad words would a nice feature :)

I know how to solve the problem as soon as it happens, but if that happens and I'm not immediately aware of that... well... cherry-pick is my friend :(

Looking at hooks seems that the pre-merge is (still?) missing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve your problem, but to me it seems you worry about this too much.

You have nothing to lose when fetching. In fact, it is always good, because the remote branches reflect the remote repositories' commit history.

If you merge with the remote branch by mistake, you can always return to the commit you were on using `git reset --hard`. (If you have any working directory changes, `git stash; git reset --hard; git stash pop;`